# StringBounds of htmlized string

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to calculate  the bounds of a htmlized String in Java Swing?

I tried using the `BasicHtml.createHTMLView`, but kept getting the same `prefSpan`; irrespective of the component font.

Regards,
Pavan

Answer (score 0):

Is this going to be displayed in a JLabel?

Try SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabel(...)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use `BasicHtml.createHTMLView()` to measure the changing preferred size of an HTML string on a `JButton` as follows:

```
for (int size = 1; size <= 7; size++)
{
    final String text = "<HTML><FONT SIZE='" + size + "'>Foo</FONT></HTML>";
    final JButton button = new JButton(text);
    final View htmlView = BasicHTML.createHTMLView(button, text);
    System.out.println("Preferred span: X=" + 
                       htmlView.getPreferredSpan(View.X_AXIS) +
                       ", Y=" + htmlView.getPreferredSpan(View.Y_AXIS));
}
```

This produced the following output:

```
Preferred span: X=15.0, Y=10.0
Preferred span: X=18.0, Y=14.0
Preferred span: X=20.0, Y=16.0
Preferred span: X=27.0, Y=19.0
Preferred span: X=33.0, Y=24.0
Preferred span: X=45.0, Y=32.0
Preferred span: X=66.0, Y=47.0
```

Am I missing something here?  I'm not sure what the difference is between the case described in your question and the example I give here.